# Find first/last event according to time tree in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I created a time tree (Day-Month-Year) and assigned events to it. Now I try to find the first and the last event for a user, who causes the events. This is my code to find the last event (assuming all events happen in the same month):

```
match (day:Day)<--(event:Event)-->(user:User{userID:"007"})
with MAX(day.Day) AS max
match (day) where day.Day=max
return day
```

**But this query returns ALL days, and not only the one with the highest .Day-Property.**

After finding the node, i will process with it, so solutions as the following are not suitable

```
  RETURN ... ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 1
```

Thanks a lot!

Note: Time-Tree-Model is designed is shown in the picture. 
*Source:* *graphaware.com*
[image]

Comment: Hello @Boris! I did not understand clearly your problem. Can you add more details about it? What is the expected output? Or which error message are you getting? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Bruno! I edited it in the post!

Comment: This is not a issue related to the option "Connect result nodes"? Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45760733/6835358).

Comment: no the query just returns a few nodes, instead of the one witt maximum value. So the maximum value is calculated more than once and logically matches to more than one node. I think it then makes a few iterations and picks the suitable node every time..

Comment: Any possibility of sharing the data set you are using to query?

Comment: should we continue in a room again? ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153464/discussion-between-bruno-peres-and-boris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that works:

```
match (day:Day)<--(event:Event)-->(user:User{UserID:"007"})
with MAX(day.Day) AS max, collect(day) as days
match (day) where day in days anD  day.Day=max
return day
```